# XSLT file convert > to &gt; but I need the same symbol in my java script function

Tags: javascript, xslt

When I compile my xslt file it replce > operator of my javascript function to `&gt;`
(gt)

How I put the same Symbol in my html page when compiling the xslt file.

How I achieve the same

Comment: kindly post your xslt

Comment: CDATA is your friend.

Comment: I guess, you are talking about creating an HTML file with some JavaScript in it. In this case using extern JavaScript files is often the best solution.  Alternatively, you can write `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> &gt; </xsl:text>` in your XSTL file. Then you will get > in the output.